# Verificar se linha na base de dados existe, se não, recomeçar query de novo

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho uma base de dados e gostaria de ir buscar sempre o valor antes, e eu tenho usado por exemplo:

Vou buscar uma notícia, e nessa página tem um link para a notícia anterior, e eu vou busca-la buscando o id da noticia atual - 1, mas desta forma, ele irá para ids que possam não existir ou terem sido apagados, existe forma de ignorar os vazios e fazer a query de novo?

Comment: Você pode buscar com a condição que o id seja menor que o atual e limitar ao primeiro registro. Por exemplo: SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE id < 3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 -- Anterior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi vc quer buscar a última notícia antes da notícia que vc está.
Se você usa o ID como Integer seqüencial da para fazer algo como:

```
  SELECT columns FROM noticias WHERE id < 'id_noticia_atual' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Basicamente você vai buscar qual o último ID antes da sua notícia atual e em seguida buscar qual a notícia de acordo com o id que você encontrou.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode buscar com base no ID atual e limitando a quantidade de registro.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM noticia WHERE id < 3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 -- Essa seria a noticia anterior
SELECT * FROM noticia WHERE id > 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 -- Essa seria a próxima
```

Também pode fazer tudo em uma query. No Postgres por exemplo, você pode trazer cada noticia em uma coluna com um json.

Ex:

```
select to_json(noticia) as atual,
       to_json((
                 SELECT noticia
                 FROM noticia
                 WHERE id < 2
                 ORDER BY id DESC
                 LIMIT 1
       )) as anterior,
       to_json((
                 SELECT noticia
                 FROM noticia
                 WHERE id > 2
                 ORDER BY id
                 LIMIT 1
       )) as proxima
from noticia
where id = 2
```